# Open FTP passive port on GCP for CentOS

Tags: ssh, ftp, centos7, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created the network rules for allowing the traffic on passive ports range 49152-65535 in Google Cloud, but I am unable to login into the file manager using FileZilla. It still shows "227 Entering Passive Mode (35,223,231,145,245,122)".

[firewall rule Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIPMl.png)

Comment: You can potentially have two concurrent firewall configurations:  the ones maintained within your CentOS (netfilter/iptables) and external  [GCP firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) . When both are active you need to open ports and port ranges in both.

Comment: First, don't use FTP servers. Your login and password are sent in the clear. Given that, the GCP firewall rule is correct for the port that is being opened (62,842). Turn on Filezilla debugging and post the output. Post the log file for your FTP server.

Comment: [FileZilla configuration](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Setting_up_FileZilla_Client) seems to be fairly straight forward.  You also need to check the [target tags](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#rule_assignment) on your instance. As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-discussion/dnNQwdfMBUw/PVBdA4oCBwAJ), If a target tag is specified for a GCE firewall rule, the target VM instance has to also be tagged with the same value

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of tutorials that you can follow to configure a FTP/SFTP server on Google Cloud, keep in mind that this is not Google documentation.

https://cloudinfrastructureservices.co.uk/how-to-setup-filezilla-secure-ftp-server-on-google-cloud-server-2016/
https://www.onepagezen.com/google-cloud-ftp-filezilla-quick-start

Regarding your current configuration, I agree with the previous users, you should also open the ports on the Firewall of CentOS, and apply the tag you defined on the Firewall Rule on the CentOS Instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have created the network rules for allowing the traffic on passive ports range https://scopepet.com/merle-goldendoodle-your-complete-breed-guide/in Google Cloud, but I am unable to login into the file manager using FileZilla. It still shows "227 Entering Passive Mode